# Is it possible to render the "source code" for a Ruby class that includes any included models?

Tags: ruby, abstract-syntax-tree

Say, I have the following Ruby:

```
module Nameable
  def name
    "John"
  end
end

class User
  include Nameable
  def email
    "john@example.com"
  end
end
```

Is there a way to display, print or review the "expanded source code" of the entire "User"? I'm not sure what the term would be, but with "expanded source code" I mean the code, in Ruby (so not an AST), that has the included parts included:

```
class User
  def name
    "John"
  end

  def email
    "john@example.com"
  end
end
```

Bonuspoints when a solution can also display the code for inherited behaviour.

Comment: You can't flatten it. `User` could override `name` and call `super` which would not exist any more.

Comment: Easiest way `user.instance_methods`, will show you list the methods name.

Comment: @Stefan. It makes the problem harder, but not impossible. You could replace `super` with an alias, and keep the old `name` as a private method under an alias.

Comment: Should your method also include all methods from `Object`? If not, why not?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I don't mind that much. But for completeness, I've used the answers code and made "excluded parents" a second argument in my implementation. That way one can pick and choose what parents to include.

Comment: @stefan: correct. And in case of inheritance a good point. For modules, in theory too, but since "overriding the method from a module and calling super" is often considered a codesmell, because hard to follow and reason about, you don't see it that often. AFAIKR.

Comment: @berkes: it's only a codesmell because it is so often so badly explained. Including a module makes it the superclass of the class and the old superclass becomes the superclass of the module. Bam. That's it. There's really nothing more to it. Everything else follows from there: method resolution, `super`, `ancestors`, it all makes sense, once you understand that simple concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method_source [gem](https://github.com/banister/method_source).

```
require 'method_source'

def flatten_source_code(klass)
  excluded_parents = [Kernel, Object, BasicObject]
  type = klass.instance_of?(Module) ? "module" : "class"
  puts "#{type} #{klass}"

  (klass.ancestors-excluded_parents).reverse.each do |ancestor|
    ancestor.instance_methods(false).each do |method_name|
      method = ancestor.instance_method(method_name)
      script, line = method.source_location
      if script then
        puts
        puts "  # #{script} (line #{line})"
        puts method.source
      else
        puts
        puts "  #  def #{method_name}"
        puts "  #  end"
      end
    end
  end
  puts "end"
end

module Nameable
  def name
    "John"
  end
end

class User
  include Nameable
  def email
    "john@example.com"
  end
end


flatten_source_code(User)

puts 

flatten_source_code(Nameable)

#=>
# class User
#
#   # flatten_source_code.rb (line 27)
#   def name
#     "John"
#   end
#
#   # flatten_source_code.rb (line 34)
#   def email
#     "john@example.com"
#   end
# end

# module Nameable
#
#   # flatten_source_code.rb (line 27)
#   def name
#     "John"
#   end
# end
```

It will not work perfectly for more complex cases, but it does the job for your example.

Just for fun, with :

```
module Nameable
  def name
    "John"
  end

  def email
    "included john@example.com"
  end
end

module AnotherModule
  def email
    "prepended john@example.com"
  end
end

class User
  include Nameable
  prepend AnotherModule
  def email
    "john@example.com"
  end
end

flatten_source_code(User)
puts "u = User.new"
puts "puts u.name"
puts "puts u.email"
```

Launching `ruby flatten_source_code.rb | ruby` returns :

```
John
prepended john@example.com
```

So the displayed Ruby code is valid and respects inheritance order.
It will define the same method multiple times, though.

You could keep an Hash of `|method_name,method_source|`. If a method overrides an old one and calls `super`, you could define the old method as  as a private `old_method_name_from_Module_blabla` and replace `super` accordingly.